# Simple household finance website

Tags: webapp-rec

I search for a simple web-application to manage household buyings and keep track of the costs. A simple Website where I can add my bills and get monthly statistics.

[NotreManage](http://github.com/aaronmueller/notre-menage) looks very promising but its not finish yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use [buxfer](http://www.buxfer.com) and highly recommend it.  http://www.buxfer.com

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give a try, thanks.

Comment: Buxfer seems dying; blog not updated, website down all the time. I am considering moving.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: http://www.mint.com

Comment: It's also not available in all countries. It is not available in Australia for example.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for this myself a while back, and every one I looked at had drawbacks. Finally, I made myself a Google spreadsheet to track and manage my expenses against my budget.

I've created a template for others to copy:

http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AuVj-q5UD9HxdFRlTDFYS3RPNG9vcS1iWUNSUE5MN2c&output=html

Comment: Thats great, but I want a tool to record all buyings not just the monthly expenses. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yup, I use it to track all of my purchases, discretionary (like groceries, clothes, etc), and fixed costs (mortgages, phone bill, etc). I watch it affect my budget, see how much I have left in that category for the month, and see the proportion of my money that I spend on each category.

Answer (score 0):

Money strands (money.strands.com) & Mint.com

Answer (score 0):

My bank has partnered with Quicken [Finance Works](http://www.financeworks.com) and offers that for account information.  It can tie directly into your credit card accounts if you have setup online accounts so you can keep track of everything from within Finance Works.  Provides charts and graphs showing expenses, trends, and allows you to set monthly goals (budgets).  I would highly recommend you visit their site and use the Find A Financial Institution to see if your current bank participates.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [**money2manage.com**](http://www.money2manage.com) to manage all my household finance. Almost 2 years now and it is still perfect and working. Give it a try.